# python RegOpenKeyEx() HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE not defined error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywin32

I have been trying to manupulate registry key from python using the win32api module however
when I run this three lines of code

```
import win32api
import win32con

reghandle = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Google\\",0,       win32con.KEY_READ)
```

it gives me back the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\MMS-auto\key.py", line 4, in 
   reghandle = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\Google\",0,                    win32con.KEY_READ) 
   NameError: name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' is not defined

I've looked up the win32api documentation and I reckon I gave the functinon the right argument...
Can anyone pleae help out or give me any hint?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` is a constant defined in the `win32con` module.  You need to use the fully-qualified name.  Try this:

```
reghandle = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(win32con.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,"SOFTWARE\\Google\\",0,win32con.KEY_READ)
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know that, and it kind of says that in the documentation as well...

Comment: key : PyHKEY/int

An already open key, or any one of the following win32con constants